# Triggering AngularJS form validation with javascript chrome extension

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-extension

I am struggling to figure out a way to trigger these AngularJS classes on a form I am trying to automatically fill with a chrome extension I am making. The form (specifically a textbox) has to be validated/modified before it will be validated and therefore submitted.

I originally tried using javascript to set the value of the textbox using the value property. This did not validate the form. I then tried using a dispatch event to send a key to the textbox, which resulted in nothing being input into the text box. How can I validate the form without requiring human input, or is this not possible?

**Clarification**, I am trying to replicate this action without user input by using a chrome extension.

Reference https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_validation.asp

[image: The form before user input]

[image: Form after user input]

Comment: What does "triggering classes on a form" mean?

Comment: Form State and Input State
AngularJS is constantly updating the state of both the form and the input fields.

Input fields have the following states:

$untouched The field has not been touched yet
$touched The field has been touched
$pristine The field has not been modified yet
$dirty The field has been modified
$invalid The field content is not valid
$valid The field content is valid

Comment: Please put that information in your post. Also, that does not explain what you mean with "triggering classes". Whether you're talking about HTML classes or Angular ngClass, you can only set or remove those. They're not code, you can't "trigger" them?

Comment: When typing into a text form the properties change saying that the text form is validated before it can be submitted, I'm trying to validate the form. As shown on the page I linked to in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to create some events to simulate whatever angular is listening for, probably `change` or `blur`. Here's an example using `click` from mozilla:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events#Triggering_built-in_events

```
function simulateClick() {
  var event = new MouseEvent('click', {
    view: window,
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true
  });
  var cb = document.getElementById('checkbox'); 
  var cancelled = !cb.dispatchEvent(event);
  if (cancelled) {
    // A handler called preventDefault.
    alert("cancelled");
  } else {
    // None of the handlers called preventDefault.
    alert("not cancelled");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I validate the form without requiring human input

Get the forms controls:

```
var controls = $scope.tdForm.$getControls();
```

Trigger their validators:

```
controls.forEach( _ => _.$validate() );
```

From the Docs:

> ### `$validate();`
>
> Runs each of the registered validators (first synchronous validators and then asynchronous validators). If the validity changes to invalid, the model will be set to `undefined`, unless `ngModelOptions.allowInvalid` is true. If the validity changes to valid, it will set the model to the last available valid `$modelValue`, i.e. either the last parsed value or the last value set from the scope.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Form Controller API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController#$getControls)
- [AngularJS ngModelController API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$validate)

Answer (score 0):

When you type into the form, it updates the state of its controls (touched, dirty, etc.). According to how you define your fields validators (required, minLength...) the form will be valid or not after the user input.

In your submit method you should not proceed if any form fields are not valid. See [AngularJS Developer Guide — Forms](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms) or [Scotch Tutorials — AngularJS Form Validation](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation) you can have more details about AngularJS validation.

As Mike mentioned, you can use ngClass conditionally (see below) to apply some style classes only if a boolean condition occurr, for example the form is not valid.

```html
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <form name="form" novalidate class="css-form">

   <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" name="username" ng-class="{ 'error': !isValid }"/>
   <div ng-show="form.$submitted>
     <span ng-show="form.username.$error">Wrong Name</span></span>
   </div>

   <button ng-click="submit(user)"> Submit </button>
  </form>
</div>
```

```js
angular.module('formExample', [])
.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.isValid = true;

  $scope.submit= function(user) {
    if (user.name != 'Carl') {
      $scope.isValid = false;
    }
  };
}]);
```

You can always programmatically change the form states if needed. For example to set the field to pristine:

```
$scope.form.$setPristine();
$scope.form.$setUntouched();
```

> **$setPristine** sets the form's $pristine state to true, the $dirty state to false, removes the ng-dirty class and adds the ng-pristine class. 
>   
> Additionally, it sets the $submitted state to false. This method will also propagate to all the controls contained in this form.
>
> **$setUntouched** sets the form to its untouched state. 
> This method can be called to remove the 'ng-touched' class and set the form controls to their untouched state (ng-untouched class).
>   Setting a form controls back to their untouched state is often useful when setting the form back to its pristine state.

---

**UPDATE**

Now it is clear what you are attempting to achieve. The two methods above can be used to set the form state, but if you want to validate it from code (this can be done passing the form to a service or directly in the controller for instance) then `$validate()` method will allow you to achieve that as mentioned by George.

Comment: Yes but how do I recreate the human input using js? If i set the value of the textbox to what i desire using js it still displays it as being in a pristine state?

Comment: I updated the answer with the `$setPristine` method.

Comment: No, I added clarification in the post.